# How would I count the aces in each of the decks for the players?

Tags: python

```
import random
import itertools
     
carddeck = list(itertools.product(['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'], ['Spade', 'Club', 'Diamond', 'Heart']))
random.shuffle(carddeck)

def player1(n):
     for cards_1 in range(n):
          print('Player 1:', carddeck[cards_1][0],carddeck[cards_1][1])
          carddeck.remove(carddeck[cards_1])

def player2(n):
     for cards_2 in range(n):
          print('Player 2:', carddeck[cards_2][0],carddeck[cards_2][1])
          

print('Player 1 Hand')
player_1_hand = player1(5)
print('          ')
print('          ')
print('Player 2 Hand')
player_2_hand = player2(5)
     

#check to see how many aces player one has 



#check to see how many aces player two has
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of aces in a hand or deck can be counted like this:

```
sum(1 for card in carddeck if card[0] == 'A')
```

Comment: Or just `sum(card[0] == 'A' for card in carddeck)` since a boolean is an integer (check it with `isinstance(True, int)`) and `True` is treated as `1` and `False` as `0`.